# How to resolve error fetching product from Shopify API

Tags: next.js, shopify

I am trying to fetch products from shopify API but don't understand why it's throwing an an error set in my catch statement. The error says

```
error - utils/fetchShop.js (28:10) @ productData
Error: Products not fetched
  26 |     return data;
  27 |   } catch (error) {
> 28 |     throw new Error('Products not fetched');
     |          ^
  29 |   }
  30 | }
```

Can you help me figure out what I am doing wrong here. So basically I am

1. Creating a function called productData that will accept a query.
2. productData it will make a POST request to the Shopify Storefront GraphQL API using the set headers and return the json response.
3. productData function will return the data to the getAllProducts function which will set it equal to the allProducts variable.

Here is my code:

```js
const domain = process.env.SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_DOMAIN;
const storefrontAccessToken = process.env.SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_ACCESS_TOKEN;

async function productData(query) {
  const URL = `https://${domain}/api/2022-04/graphql.json`;

  const options = {
    endpoint: URL,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': storefrontAccessToken,
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query
    }),
  };

  try {
    const data = await fetch(URL, options).then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    });

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Products not fetched');
  }
}

export async function getAllProducts() {
  const query = `{
    products(first: 250) {
      edges {
        node {
          handle
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }`;

  const response = await productData(query);

  const slugs = response.data.products.edges ?
    response.data.products.edges :
    [];

  return slugs;
}
```

Comment: What's in the `error` object in the `catch` block?

Comment: @Aseem Gautam - it says in the console:
```
FetchError: request to https://https//spnsors.myshopify.com/api/2022-04/graphql.json failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/blkboxng/Desktop/publicTradesProperties/spnsors/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/node-fetch/index.js:1:64142)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND'
}
```

Comment: The url in the question is correct. Here is see a missing `:`, `https//`.

Comment: @AseemGautam - Thanks for your response. You are correct that the `:` is missing in my previous response to you, but it was included in the actual code saved as `URL` variable as shown above.

Comment: Are you able to make a successful request to the storefront URL outside the app (e.g. from Postman)?

Answer (score 0):

So I had this exact problem. It seems to be something to do with the URL variable being all caps.

If you change:

```
const URL = `https://${domain}/api/2022-10/graphql.json`;

endpoint: URL
```

To:

```
const _url = `https://${domain}/api/2022-10/graphql.json`;

endpoint: _url
```

That *should* fix the problem. It worked for me.

Be sure to also change the variable in your fetch too to reflect the changes.

EDIT: As this variable is immutable I have added the underscore to note this.